# Improve sentence by choosing correct option

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to eat watermelon besides mangoes because **these are the best things** that protect us from heat stroke in summer.

1. This is the best thing
2. These are the best thing
3. This is the best things
4. No improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you’ve written it is better than any of your alternatives.

I would say it like this:

> I want to eat watermelon(s) **as well as** mango(es) because these are the best things **to** protect us from heat stroke in summer.

Notice that when adding “best” it changes from “the things **that**” to “the best things **to**”.

Also, I would pluralise either both fruits, or neither.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to say "mangos" instead of "these" because there's some ambiguity as to whether "these" refers solely to mangos or to mangos and watermelons.  The context seems to imply only mangos, but that requires re-reading the sentence to be clear.